# Wiremock fails by not matching request and picking up wrong stub as closest match

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test, wiremock

I am using a wiremock response as JSON as part of my TestRunner and have included the file in my resources folder. While wiremock server starts and runs through the application, other responses are being picked up, while this is is not. While I have noticed that at times the same error occurs for other stubs as well, this has been persisting.

JSON Stub:

I have tried adding "priority" : 1 but it has not helped

```
{
  "priority" : 1,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPathPattern": "/abc/oX6%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2oQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW20Q%3D"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    "body": "{Sample JSON Response}"
  }
}
```

I have tried combinations of using "url", "urlPath", "urlPattern", "urlPathPattern" etc.

Earlier on while testing by calling the actual url before the application run ends, I used to get this error:

```
<p>Problem accessing /__files/abc/oX6w==/xyz//W2LQ==/def. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
```

But more recently, it has been the actual response that I need, but during the test run it does not pick it up.

Complete Stack trace of error:

```
HttpRequest URI: http://localhost:8090/abc/oX6%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2oQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW20Q%3D, Method: GET, Headers: {Authorization=[Bearer eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwicGNrIjoxLCJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJ0diI6Miwia2lkIjoicjRxIn0..Uju6CeetuaYsFx2lJOfqNA.9Co1RB_6L4QXIM-1BC1mQCyAh4P-_to7IG2gWZt8kOXuac9-ek-V7tbJgMqUR1kPzpsgFkLgVdgl1HuHx2sLdC-JFVH00mZjJf3S91XhX4LwJsqgCOIPjtPZpqPWESYiMAVd9o6u0ftos-fFkHYOgledyUJPCetcHviBmDBu9pIpV6hU8gG9KByi--3gF2niLPI0qcSnjQXh4JJaW_zOrhDrwjm6LMLWtwpnlL4YTjUTgwiEa4Hy5Qf9EyW-WU9I7-JLdgSiZG4pvhxvHHS7EJgJQRupy3YeckMZ4GsKpvE.qgkjli-mhlxzxJSxLuq35g], Accept=[application/json;v=5], Content-Type=[application/json;v=5], X-Message-ID=[ABC_:54:24.000487], Content-Length=[0]} body: 
[qtp161069393-18] 02 Aug 2019 17:54:27,177 ERROR WireMock        [{}]: Request was not matched:
{
  "urlPathPattern" : "abc/oX6%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2oQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW20Q%3D",
  "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:8090/abc/oX6%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2oQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW20Q%3D",
  "method" : "GET",
  "clientIp" : "127.0.0.1",
  "headers" : {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer token",
    "Accept" : "application/json;v=5",
    "User-Agent" : "Java/1.8.0_201",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "X-Message-ID" : "ABC_20190802_17:54:24.000487",
    "Host" : "localhost:8090",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json;v=5"
  },
  "cookies" : { },
  "browserProxyRequest" : false,
  "loggedDate" : 1564782867165,
  "bodyAsBase64" : "",
  "body" : "",
  "loggedDateString" : "2019-08-02T21:54:27Z"
}
Closest match:
{
  "urlPathPattern" : "abc/oX6%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2oQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW20Q%3D",
  "method" : "GET"
}
[] 02 Aug 2019 17:54:27,205 INFO  TraceRequestInterceptor [{BusinessContextIdentifier=1, Executing=Work, RelatedBusinessContext=null, WORKFLOW_TYPE=X, X-Message-ID=ABC_20190802_17:54:24.000487}]: HttpRequest URI: http://localhost:8090/abc/oX6n72M4qvox0wCYcT9uzw%3D%3D/xyz/%2FW2L4sojZbme5uX8D%2BqGUYedmP6P59Wy6Lt1izTVbCMtz%2BDh9csONCnAAIMMbNOCBTdlIorwsbhHIAsyzJ4uvQ%3D%3D/def?ghi=%2FW2L4sojZbme5uX8D%2BqGUVSZrd8ZSo9YjYpNOznFS0Q%3D StatusCode: 404
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /__files/abc/oX6w==/xyz//W2LQ==/def. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```